# Statistics ( cumulative frequency )

Tags: statistics

The question on my book is:

How many percent of the pupils got at least a $11$ on their French test??

How can i find it by look at that table ?
On that table there's absolute frequency, relative frquency, cumulative absolute frequency, cumulative relative frequency and also in percentage.

Where should I look to find out the students who got more then $11 $ points on their test?

Please help me !! i got maths exma son monday !!! :(

Answer (score 0):

In principle, if you have all of this data you could look at any of the tables. In practice, the easiest method would be just to go to cumulative relative frequency, find the cumulative relative frequency at '11' points, then subtract it from 1.

This will give you the percentage of students who got more than 11 points - notice this is slightly different from the percentage of the pupils who got *at least* an 11: at least implies exactly 11 should also be included, so you'll have to add the percent who got exactly 11 points to the figure you obtained.

Comment: i've to kno the percetnage of the pupils who got at least an 11 !! so does it mean i'v to add pupils who got more then 11 points too?? on my workboek they did 100 % - 28 % = 72% is the answer but i have no idea how ... that 28 % is the cumulative relative frequency % of pupils who got 9 points !!! But the question is people who got atleast an 11 point !!! how this is related to 9 !!

Comment: Were there any students who scored 10 points? If there are no students who scored 10 points, then this is correct, albeit almost deliberately confusing if you're just starting out. Otherwise, it must be a typo in the book. It would help if you could post the data you have.